# Batch file for listing all files from a date interval

Tags: date, batch-file, batch-processing, intervals

I need to do a batch file which order all files by a date interval, example:

```
@echo off
echo Input the date(dd/mm/yyyy):
set /p compDate=

::After that I will compare from the actual day (%date%), example:

set interval = %compDate% - %date%... *Something like that*

::After that I need to list all files from a specific directory, example:

echo Input the directory:
set /p directory=
SET Exit= %UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt

::After that I might need dir /tc to get the creation date, example:

pushd "%directory%"
dir /s /tc /a-d > %Exit%

::After that I don't know how to get only the lines which are in date interval, example:
```

Today is 19/08/2014, but I want to search all files created from day 10/07/2014.
So I have to copy all lines which have the date 10/07/2014, 11/07/2014, 12/07/2014 and so on until stop on today created files.

I tried with `findstr`, but I can't set the date interval, just a specific date to search in the .txt created.

Somebody know how to do that?

Comment: The `forfiles` command is for doing this stuff. Try using it. `XCopy` can also do it (it can list what files it would copy without copying them). Both allow selection by date. Type `xcopy /?` and `forfiles /?`.

Comment: There is no date/time calculation program or function in Batch.

Comment: `forfiles /d +26/2/2014 /p c:\windows /m *.txt /c "cmd /c echo @fpath @fdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood the request, you really don't want files created in a *given interval*, but files created *after a given date*. The Batch file below assume that the date used by the system appear in DD/MM/YYYY order:

**EDIT**: *Some modifications as reply to the comments*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Input the date(dd/mm/yyyy):
set /p compDate=
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%compDate%") do set compDate=%%c%%b%%a

echo Input the directory:
set /p directory=
SET Exit=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt

pushd "%directory%"

(for /F "tokens=1-5*" %%a in ('dir /s /od /tc /a-d') do (
   set "fileDate=%%a"
   if "!fileDate:~2,1!!fileDate:~5,1!" equ "//" (
      for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%x in ("!fileDate!") do set fileDate=%%z%%y%%x
      if !fileDate! geq %compDate% (
         set "fileSize=               %%e"
         echo %%a  %%b %%c %%d  !fileSize:~-16! %%f
      )
   )
)) > %Exit%

popd
```

Comment: Yes, I want a list of all files created created in the date or after the given date, in my system already appear DD/MM/YYYY, but this batch file don't make *.txt list, and /b in 'dir' don't display the created date.

Comment: In order to create a text file with the result, just use `(for /F ... do ( ... )) > %exit_file%`; and for the created date dsplayed by `dir`, just modify the Batch file to show the data output from `dir` itself instead of `%%~Ta`. I focused in the "date interval" problem...

Comment: I showed you how to do it with forfiles. Too easy was it.

Comment: @Noodles: Yes, it is very easy with forfiles, but it uses the last modification date instead of the creation date, as the OP requested!

Comment: I'm begginer with batch-files, sorry for that, I'll try to do it again... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes: See the edit in my answer; I think the new version is exactly what you had requested...

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses WMIC and is independent from time/date settings:

```
@echo off


setlocal

set /p compDate=Input the date(yyyymmdd): 
set /p directory=Full directory path (with no slash at the end): 
set exit_file= %UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt
break>%exit_file%

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%directory%") do (
    set "dir_drive=%%~a:"
    set "dir_path=%%~b\"    
) 

set dir_path=%dir_path:\=\\%

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "useback skip=1 tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%f in (`" wmic datafile where (drive='!dir_drive!' and path like '%dir_path%') get CreationDate^,name"`) do (
    set creation_date=%%f
    set creation_date=!creation_date:~0,8!
    set "file_name=%dir_drive%%%~g"

    if 1!creation_date! GTR 1%compDate% (
        echo  !file_name!>>%exit_file%
     )

)
exit /b 0
```

Comment: When execute the batch file, the *.txt created is empty... Not worth.